# Modifying Web.Config using SPWebConfigModification

Tags: spwebconfigmodification

I wrote the following code in my feature receiver to add a connectionString
in the web.config:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://devtools2012/sites/Test"));

SPWebConfigModification mod = new SPWebConfigModification("add[@name=\"MyConnection\"]", 
    "configuration/connectionStrings");

    mod.Owner = "ExcelServiceOwner";

    mod.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;

    mod.Value = String.Format("", "MyConnection", "Server=DEVWCMSDB2012;Database=BJS;Integrated Security=true", "System.Data.SqlClient");

    webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(mod);

    webApp.Update();

    webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
```

However, it is failing with the following error:

---

> Failed to apply web.config modifications to Web application
>   '9a38b727-bab9-44ad-93ba-a6c3b919d481'. Failed to apply web.config
>   modifications to file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config'. The Value
>   property for EnsureChildNode cannot be set to an empty value.

---

I appreciate any input you can extend  me. Regards.

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90ab7af2-7bd7-4f8e-b18f-09430dbc4ba9/sharepoint2010-spwebconfigmodification-adding-new-nodesection-in-webconfig-error?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's a formatting issue with the question then the `mod.Value = String.Format("", ...)` is giving an empty string.

You want something like:

```
mod.Value = String.Format("<add name="{0}" connectionString="{1}" ProviderName="{2}" />", ...)
```

Comment: Per, thank you for the prompt response. Much appreciated...it works!!!! Regards.